# Docker image version after migration to .net 6.0

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I have just migrated my app form .net core 3.1 to .net 6.0 and only one step left. I have file Dockerfile.publish and there if I understand correctly I need to change runetime version to match .net 6.0.

For .net core 3.1 there is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1-bionic
```

So, here is my question is it any equivalent for runtime:3.1-bionic in .net 6.0 because I can't find anything in documentation. Maybe just simple `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0` is enough? I can't find anything about that in documentation.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your `Dockerfile` whether the runtime is enough. For just running the application it'll be, but for building it, you'll need the SDK. But why not just try it and ask in case it fails here?

Comment: Rest of dockerfile is irrelevant in this questions because I just wanted to find lut whether runtime:3.1-bionic has some equivalent like runtime:6.0-bionic or it's fine to replace it with just /runtime:6.0.

Comment: It's enough, but you can specify different distributions too, including stripped-down ones. This is explained in [the .NET Dockerization docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows). The tags are listed in [the image's page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/)

Comment: @Maltion the rest of the file *is* relevant, because a typical .NET Core Dockerfile uses multi-stage builds. You need to change the `sdk` image version as well as the runtime. The versions need to match

Comment: `I can't find anything in documentation.` there's an entire section on [.NET and Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/introduction) in Microsoft's documentation. There's also a .NET section in [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/language/dotnet/). Visual Studio has tools for Docker, [documented in VS Tools for Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?toc=%2Fdotnet%2Fnavigate%2Fdevops-testing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fdotnet%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2022). That includes Docker compose and starting multiple containers at once

Comment: Finally, .NET 7 added the ability to [publish directly to a container image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container)

Comment: Yes I know that I need also change SDK image version. I already looked into this documentation and I can't see anything about runtime:6:0-bionic so I suppose that it's no longer available and I should use just runtime:6.0. @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for help.

Comment: That's because `bionic` (Ubuntu 18) is out of support.  The current LTS versions are 20 (focal) and 22 (Jammy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bionic refers to Ubuntu 18.04, which is not supported anymore. For .NET 6, tags for both Ubuntu 20.04 (`6.0-focal`) and Ubuntu 22.04 (`6.0-jammy`) are available. You can find all currently supported tags for the .NET runtime images at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/.